# Directory write protected ONLY when using Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop

I have a remote computer that I access from my computer using Remote Desktop.  There, I can read/write/delete files in a certain directory.

If I share that directory, then access it via my computer, and provide the same credentials used for accessing via Remote Desktop, I am limited to read access.

The account used for both Remote Desktop and for accessing the share is an Admin account.  Just for good measure, I even gave the User account full access.

Specifics:
Both my and the remote PC are running Windows 10.
I'm running Remote Desktop/sharing on a VPN provided by ZeroTier.

To the best of my knowledge, accessing the directory should have the same behavior regardless of whether doing so via a share or Remote Desktop.  Am I wrong?  If not, what should I look for?

Comment: What do you mean by "share that directory" ? How many computers are involved here?

Comment: 2 computers.  Go to the remote PC's directory's properties via Remote Desktop, click the sharing tab, and share the directory.  Now, on a local PC, go to a DOS prompt and enter \\remote-pc-name\d.  You'll be prompted for the credentials, where I enter the same credentials used to Remote Desktop into the remote PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security rights for shares are placed on 2 locations. The security tab and also the share tab itself. By default, if you make a share, its shared as read only, and you have to edit the permissions to include write rights.

When you access a file or folder locally or through RDP, only the security settings are taken into place. When accessing through a share, both the security settings AND the share settings are taken into account.

I'm positive you have not set the share rights.

If you have, and you are opening a file and it is read only, make sure you have not opened that file elsewhere at the same time too.

Comment: Thanks.  It was missing the security setting that was the problem.

Comment: Interesting. I guess having local admin circumvented the security setting or would prompt you an UAC dialog every time you would want to make changes.